Finish this proof of gradient in polar coordinates
In my exercise, we want to derive the formula of the gradient in polar coordinates.
We end up showing that
$$\nabla f(r\cos \theta , r\sin\theta)=\frac{ \partial g }{ \partial r }(r,\theta)e_{r }+\frac{1}{r}\frac{ \partial g }{ \partial \theta }(r,\theta)e_{\theta}$$
where $g(r,\theta)=f(r\cos\theta,r\sin\theta)$ and $f:\mathbb{R}^{2}\to \mathbb{R}$ is differentiable.
Now the exercise ends there. But I think we still need to prove that $\nabla g(r,\theta)=\nabla f(r\cos\theta,r\sin\theta)$ which looks wrong to me. Am I missing something obvious?

Edit: Since there are ambiguous notations let me write the whole exercice:
Let $f:\mathbb{R}^{2}\to \mathbb{R}$ a differentiable function. And $g(r,\theta)=f(r\cos\theta,r\sin\theta)$
Chain rule:
$$
\frac{ \partial g }{ \partial r } (r,\theta)=\cos\theta \frac{ \partial f }{ \partial x } (r\cos\theta,r\sin\theta) + \sin\theta \frac{ \partial f }{ \partial y } (r\cos  \theta, r\sin\theta)
$$
$$
\frac{ \partial g }{ \partial \theta } (r,\theta)=-r \sin\theta \frac{ \partial f }{ \partial x } (r\cos\theta,r\sin\theta) + r\cos\theta \frac{ \partial f }{ \partial y } (r\cos  \theta, r\sin\theta)
$$
Inverting the system we get:
$$
\frac{ \partial f }{ \partial x } (r\cos \theta,r\sin\theta)=\cos\theta \frac{ \partial g }{ \partial r } (r,\theta)-\frac{1}{r}\sin\theta \frac{ \partial g }{ \partial \theta } (r,\theta)
$$
$$
\frac{ \partial f }{ \partial y } (r\cos \theta,r\sin\theta)=\sin\theta \frac{ \partial g }{ \partial r } (r,\theta)+\frac{1}{r}\cos\theta \frac{ \partial g }{ \partial \theta } (r,\theta)
$$
Plugin this into the gradient formula for $f$:  $\nabla f(x,y)=\frac{ \partial f }{ \partial x }(x,y)\vec{i}+\frac{ \partial f }{ \partial y }(x,y)\vec{j}$ replacing $(x,y)=(r\cos \theta, r\sin\theta)$
We end up showing that:
$$\nabla f(r\cos \theta , r\sin\theta)=\frac{ \partial g }{ \partial r }(r,\theta)e_{r }+\frac{1}{r}\frac{ \partial g }{ \partial \theta }(r,\theta)e_{\theta}$$
Notice here there is no ambiguity in the notation: by $\nabla f(r\cos \theta , r\sin\theta)$ we mean "gradient of $f$ at $(r\cos \theta, r\sin\theta)$. Not gradient of $g$ at $(r, \theta)$.

Why is that wrong given your correct definition of $g,?$

What can be criticized though is that the notation $\nabla f(r\cos\theta,r\sin\theta)$ is ambiguous. I am addressing these issues in this answer.

@KurtG.  I edited my original post to clear up any ambiguity in the notations. I am still confused how to finish the demonstration. Alternatively, I would appreciate any resource that rigorously derives the gradient in polar coordinates.

By what exactly are you confused? What you did is correct. No resource does it any better.

See the reply of Graham Kemp. Basically, if $\nabla g(r,\theta) = \nabla(f\circ h)(r,\theta)\quad\neq\quad (\nabla f)\circ h(r,\theta)=\nabla f(r\cos\theta,r\sin\theta)$
And $$\nabla f(r\cos \theta , r\sin\theta)=\frac{ \partial g }{ \partial r }(r,\theta)e_{r }+\frac{1}{r}\frac{ \partial g }{ \partial \theta }(r,\theta)e_{\theta}$$
We have a problem, because we want to show that   $$\nabla g(r,\theta) = \frac{ \partial g }{ \partial r }(r,\theta)e_{r }+\frac{1}{r}\frac{ \partial g }{ \partial \theta }(r,\theta)e_{\theta}$$

You wrote yourself in the edited post that $\nabla f(r\cos\theta,r\sin\theta)$ is the gradient of $f$ at $(r\cos\theta,r\sin\theta),.$ Not gradient of $g$ at $(r,\theta),.$ Which of Graham's correct but different equations therefore applies? Edit: in that variable transformation business I recommend (as I did in the linked answer) to forget about the notation $\nabla$ completely. The partial differential notation is sufficient and much clearer.

I appreciate your response. And yes the partial notation is much clearer. But I won't be able to sleep until I get what is wrong with the nabla notation. To clarify  we want to show:
$$(1)\nabla g(r,\theta) = \frac{ \partial g }{ \partial r }(r,\theta)e_{r }+\frac{1}{r}\frac{ \partial g }{ \partial \theta }(r,\theta)e_{\theta}$$
But instead we have proven:
$$(2) \nabla f(r\cos \theta , r\sin\theta)=\frac{ \partial g }{ \partial r }(r,\theta)e_{r }+\frac{1}{r}\frac{ \partial g }{ \partial \theta }(r,\theta)e_{\theta}$$
Which seems to imply a contradiction when you take (1) + (2)

Let us continue this discussion in chat.

"But I won't be able to sleep until I get what is wrong with the nabla notation." That's exactly why I won't continue that discussion on chat. I said everything what is to say about that notation.

The thing is, the gradient at the end of the day is a vector. And I need to get the components of that gradient. Its not enough for me to know how to compute the partial derivatives (which is all you do in your post and which I also do, correctly, in my post). So its not me wanting no matter what to use nabla, its that my problem is not in computing the partial derivatives. Also just because you don't like one notation, does not prevent everyone else from using it, especially since I made a lot of effort to explicitely name every variable.

Hint: The the components of the gradient are the partial derivatives of which I thought they are now clear.

Also: The notation $\nabla_{(r,\theta)}$ and $\nabla_{(x,y)},,$ or something similar along those lines, should get you out of the mess with the naked and ambiguous $\nabla,.$ The question is not what a gradient is (I hope we know that). The question is how we denote it assuming we know what we are doing.

That notation is a good idea. Basically we should be able to prove that $$\nabla_{x,y} f(r\cos\theta,r\sin\theta)=\nabla_{r,\theta}g(r,\theta)$$
Therefore finishing the proof. I haven't typed it out yet. But I checked it empirically (taking $g(r,\theta)=r^{3}\cos\theta$ as an example). It also means the proof was not complete because that last step is not trivial.


But I think we still need to prove that $\nabla g(r,\theta)=\nabla f(r\cos\theta,r\sin\theta)$ which looks wrong to me.

It looks wrong because it is wrong.
Let $h(r,\theta)= {[r\cos\theta,r\sin\theta]}$.
Then: $\nabla g(r,\theta) = \nabla(f\circ h)(r,\theta)\quad\neq\quad (\nabla f)\circ h(r,\theta)=\nabla f(r\cos\theta,r\sin\theta)$

Yes indeed, if you apply the chain rule correctly, the two are different.
I edited my original post with the entire derivation. I would appreciate if you point out what is wrong in the reasoning. Because clearly something is wrong.
